# For Loop Won't Print x Amount of Times

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, random

I need to make a random generator within a "for" loop that will run 100, 1,000,000, and 1,000,000,000 times. The idea is to simulate a roulette wheel spinning that many times, and then calculating:

1. How many reds appear.
2. How many blacks appear.
3. How many times a number appears twice in a row.
4. How many times a number appears three times in a row.
5. Longest string of even numbers.
6. Longest string of odd numbers.

I have already coded an `if/else if` statement to assign the numbers 0-36 a color, and written `for` loop containing a random generator and a getter for the colors (I haven't figured out exactly how I'm going to count the strings of recurring numbers). My loop should reiterate 100 times, and according to everything I've read, it should. However, when it prints, it only prints 47 lines. This leads me to believe my loop is only initializing 47 times. If this is the case, what am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RouletteGenerator
{
public static void main(String[] args) {

RouletteWheel wheelGenerator = new RouletteWheel();
Random generator = new Random();

//FIELDS
int random;
int red = 0;
int black = 0;
int two = 0;
int three = 0;
int even = 0;
int odd = 0;
int lastNumber = 0;
int lastNumber2 = 0;


for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    random = generator.nextInt(37);
    wheelGenerator.setNumber(random);
    String numberColor = wheelGenerator.getColor();
    System.out.println("Your random number is: " + random + " - " +      numberColor);
    }

    }
}
```

This is the code for my other class, which gives each random number a color based on an actual roulette wheel.

```
public class RouletteWheel
{
/**
 * FIELDS
 */
int rouletteNumber;

/**
 * DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
 */
RouletteWheel() {
    rouletteNumber = 0;
}

/**
 * SET THE NUMBER FIELD (SETTER)
 */
void setNumber(int numberIn) {
    rouletteNumber = numberIn;
}

/**
 * GETS THE NUMBER'S COLOR
 */
String getColor() {
   if(rouletteNumber ==0) {
        return "Green";
    } else if(rouletteNumber % 2 == 0) {
        //EVEN NUMBERS
        if(rouletteNumber <= 10) {
            //1-10
            return "Black";
        } else if(rouletteNumber <= 18) {
            //11-18
            return "Red";
        } else if(rouletteNumber <= 28) {
            //19-28
            return "Black";
        } else {
            //29-36
            return "Red";
        }
    } else {
        //ODD NUMBERS
        if(rouletteNumber >= 29) {
            //29-36
            return "Black";
        } else if(rouletteNumber >= 19) {
            //19-28
            return "Red";
        } else if(rouletteNumber >= 11) {
            //11-18
            return "Black";
        } else {
            //1-10
            return "Red";
        }   
    }
} 

}
```

Comment: I see no reason for the loop to stop early. Are you sure it does not throw an exception? Does the program end correctly?

Comment: Does the program just exits or you get an error after printing 47 times?  Is it always 47 times.  The code looks correct.  The only thing it will iterate 101 times because you are going from 0 to 100 inclusive (i <= 100)

Comment: Can you post the code for `setNumber()` and `getColor()`? it might fail there.

Comment: is it possible to have the code of RouletteWheel?

Comment: I receive no error or exception. It correctly outputs 47 lines every time, but stops at 47. I checked the VM and it stops as well, telling me the code has finished. There shouldn't be anything causing it to stop early, as far as I know?

Comment: Can you print out i in the System.out.println()  System.out.println(i+": Your random number is: " + random + " - " +      numberColor);

Comment: I posted the code for my other class, for those who asked for it. @Yan, it appears my loop is starting at 54. My output looks like this:

54Your random number is: 3 - Red
55Your random number is: 18 - Red
56Your random number is: 10 - Black
57Your random number is: 1 - Red
58Your random number is: 33 - Black
59Your random number is: 3 - Red
60Your random number is: 19 - Red

...and so on. Up to 100.

Comment: Your code runs fine on my computer. Gave me 101 results.

Comment: You know you can scroll up and down the output console right?

Comment: @Guy, which program are you using for coding and output? Bluej is only giving me lines 54 and up, meaning it appears to start at 54 and goes to 100. It never gives me 100 lines of output.

Comment: I'm using simple Eclipse, without any program.

Comment: By the way, it wouldn't get to line 54 without going threw lines 0 to 53. I never worked with Bluej but I imagine the output console is not very different.

Comment: @Guy I figured, I was just worried that my data analysis on the results would be skewed if my loop wasn't reiterating the correct amount of times. Since it appeared to only be initializing 47 times, I needed to troubleshoot and no one I asked could tell me why. I'm beginning to think BlueJ might be limited in the number of lines it puts out in a run window, but that really shouldn't be.

Comment: I have never used BlueJ but i don't it would be limited to only 50 lines.  Change your loop to go from 1-30 and see if it prints all.  There is have to be a way to scroll up.  Maybe take a screenshot and post it.